# How can I make Chrome and Firefox treat tables around floats the same?

Tags: css, html-table, css-float

I was looking at a method to move a right-floated image down and have content wrap around the top, side, and bottom.

Then since I wanted a vertically-centered bullet point for the content, I decided to use single-row tables. (I couldn't find a way without using tables...)

That's when I realized that Chrome and Firefox don't wrap tables around floated elements the same. In fact, Chrome does it right and Firefox doesn't.

Is there a way to make them consistent either way?

See http://jsfiddle.net/XPd9J/49/ and change the width of the result to see what I mean.

```
<div id="leftfloater"></div>
<div id="rightfloater"></div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="centerbullet">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/32/Actions-arrow-left-icon.png" />
        </td>
        <td>
            Watch behavior when changing result width. Fox != Chrome!
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(Using Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m and FF 23.0.1)

Comment: probably that because of an absence of the table's `width` propertie

Comment: upd: and vertical centering of the buller (in this case) can be done with a pure `css` (without tables)

Comment: upd:? I tried making a vertically centered background bullet, but backgrounds don't wrap. Can you modify my fsfiddle to work without using tables or should I ask a new question?

Comment: I think it's something like that http://jsfiddle.net/XPd9J/64/

Comment: Thanks. It's close, but the content doesn't wrap around the top of the right-floated box. (I was trying out a technique that moved a right-floated image down by inserting a zero-width left-floated image before it. That's why my example had the "clear:both" in the right-floated div.) In your example, I tried adjusting the width of the content to 100% or a fixed 500px, but neither worked like I hoped!

Comment: that seems impossible (as for me) =)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's weird.  But it does seem like adding `table{clear:left;}` will make Firefox behave more like Chrome in this specific case.

Comment: That makes it wrap around the right-floated box, but of course I'd like it to wrap around the left-floated box too!